# Need to turn all text into plain text/ASCII (I think?)

Tags: python, encoding, mechanize

I am trying to scrape a story from a website that I work for, when you put in the URL, which then posts to various news partners that we have. The problem is that, special characters seem to be giving it hiccups. I'm trying to do .replace on the string, but it doesn't seem to work particularly well.

Is there anyway to force an output to be entirely regular text that should be postable anywhere? Like, with no special characters?

My current code is:

```
from __future__ import division
#from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
import spynner
from mechanize import Browser
import SendKeys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

br = Browser()
url = "http://www.benzinga.com/trading-ideas/long-ideas/11/07/1815251/bargain-hunting-for-mid-caps-five-stocks-worth-taking-a-look-"
page = br.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

artcontent = soup.find('div', {'class': 'article-content'})

title = artcontent.find('h1', {'id': 'title'})

title = title.string

try:
    title = title.replace("&#039;", "'")
except:
    pass

authorname = artcontent.find('div', {'class': 'node full'})
authorname = authorname.find('div', {'class': 'article-submitted'})
authorname = authorname.find('div', {'class': 'info'})
authorname = authorname.find('a')
authorname = authorname.string

story = artcontent.find('div', {'class': 'node full'})
story = story.find('div', {'class': 'content clear-block'})
story = story.findAll('p', {'class': None})

#story = [str(x).replace("<p>","\n\n").replace("</p>","") for x in story]

story = [str(x) for x in story]

storyunified = ''.join(story)

#try:
#    storyunified = storyunified.strip("\n")
#except:
#    pass
#try:
#    storyunified = storyunified.strip("\n")
#except:
#    pass

#print(storyunified)

try:
storyunified = storyunified.replace("Â", "")
except:
    pass

try:
    storyunified = storyunified.replace("â€", "\'")
except:
    pass

try:
    storyunified = storyunified.replace('“', '\"')
except:
    pass

try:
    storyunified = storyunified.replace('"', '\"')
except:
     pass

try:
    storyunified = storyunified.replace('”', '\"')
except:
    pass

try:
    storyunified = storyunified.replace("âﾀ", "")
except:
    pass

try:
    storyunified = storyunified.replace("â€", "")
except:
    pass
```

As you can see, I'm trying to manually get rid of them, and it doesn't always seem to be working.

I then try to post using Spynner, but I don't see that code as as critical. I post to the Forbes Blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this article and see if you are already familiar with the principles it discusses: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

My instinct is that your news partners are able to accept text beyond just what ASCII can encode.  You just need to ensure that your application handles character-strings and byte-strings correctly, and everything should work naturally.

In Python 2.x, `'this text'` is a byte-string and `u'this text'` is a character-string.  In Python 3.x, `'this text'` is a character-string and `b'this text'` is a byte-string.  Byte-strings have a `.decode(encoding)` method and character-strings have a `.encode(encoding)` method.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was wrestling with character encodings in Python the other day.

Try this:

```
import unicodedata

storyunified = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', storyunified).encode('ascii','ignore').decode("ascii")
```

One thing to not is that it will remove the offending characters instead of replacing them. To change this behavior, you can change `ignore` to `replace`, but I haven't done any testing on that.